# how to edit existing terms and conditions

Tags: magento2.2, cache, reindex, static-content-deploy, terms-and-conditions

After adding **term & condition** in **magento 2.2.6**, I can't find the **edit** or **delete** option. 
Tried to **clear cahe**, **reindex**, **deploy static** but noting working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you check the error log? is there anything? tried once this command **php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

Comment: My site running in shared host, so this command will work?
I only tried clear cahe, reindex, cron, deploy static. 

Its a bug, created new site in other host & test. Still same problem there.

Comment: yes in shared host above command will work try it, then how you remove the cache, reindex, and static deploy?

Comment: Ok done but finished showing execution time 102.

Problem still there.. is there any way to delete anyone of terms & condition that I added recently? i'm not a developer :)
https://imgur.com/UaYsMaQ

Comment: On the Admin sidebar, tap Stores. Then under Settings, choose Terms and Conditions -> Click which you want to delete and click Delete Condition button

Comment: This is how I can see terms & condition page. I can add new but cant edit or delete. Always shows blank.

https://ibb.co/jXLzjK

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link.I hope this will fix your admin Terms & Conditions issue.
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/checkout-agreement-store-doesn-t-exist/m-p/107947#M6746